# Swagger Keeps getting unauthorised Error even Authorise using JWT Token

Tags: .net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, swagger

I am working in .NET 5 Web API with Azure AD Authentication. One of my Controller is protected with [Authorize]. When trying to call those API from Swagger I was getting Unauthorized Error.

So in my startup I have configured like this

```
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MyProject", Version = "v1.0.0" });



            c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows()
                {
                    Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
                    {
                        AuthorizationUrl = new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Configuration["TenantId"]}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"),
                        TokenUrl = new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Configuration["TenantId"]}/oauth2/v2.0/token")
                        
                    }
                }
            });


        });
```

So it shown an Authorize button on Top and on clicking on that prompts me to specify client id

[image]

I specified the client id and clicked on Authorize. But its saying the request must contain Scope parameter

[image]

I have not idea how to deal with it or not sure this is the correct way to Authorize swagger. Please share your suggestion. I am pretty new to Swagger

Also its asking me for Client ID. But is there is anyway (If I following the correct way) to specify the clientid in code so no need to specify it when prompt?

Answer (score 1):

you should add `AddSecurityRequirement`

```
 c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, // or ReferenceType.Parameter
                                Id = "oauth2"
                            }
                        },
                        new string[] {}
                    }
                });
```